# I just get html with no css as my wordpress page, I can't get to the admin panel, or the wp-login.php page

Tags: wordpress

I changed the address (I think site location) of my wordpress url to a different  url. When I did that, I could no longer access the admin page or the wp-login page but I got to the website.

I'm really confused on whats going on, I also tried setting up phpmyadmin (after the fact) and it redirects me to the page I already made.

So basically, how can I get the visual admin page back so I can continue making pages, and how can I get it to where its not showing raw html.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) and follow one of the steps. I had the same issue with my site and editing the `fuctions.php` file resolved this.

The two main fixes usually are:

**Edit WP-Config.php**

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
```

*Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site*

**Edit Functions.php**

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

*Add these two lines to the file, immediately after the initial `<?php` line.*

Comment: I've used these methods and I still come with problems. I try to FTP my site but it doesn't recognize the address (the IP) but if I put the IP in my browser its fine.

There is a disconnect here but I don't know where it is.